# Update listview when run onResume() in Android

Tags: android, listview

I create a listview get all contact from address book of Android. I try to update listview by onResume() but It's not working.

Here is my code:

```
public class Display extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> email1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma ;
    ListView lv;
    int countContact;
    TextView textViewManyCount;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);

        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
            ma = new MyAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(ma);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
            lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            textViewManyCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewManyCount);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        countContact = phones.getCount();

        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
          String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
          String email = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
          System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber); 
          name1.add(name);
          phno1.add(phoneNumber);
          email1.add(email);
        }

        phones.close();
     }
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
       LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView textViewName,textViewPhone,textViewEmail;
        MyAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)Display.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
             vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_user, null); 
            textViewName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPhone = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone);
            textViewEmail = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);


            textViewName.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
            textViewPhone.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
            textViewEmail.setText("Email :"+ email1.get(position));
            textViewManyCount.setText("Contacts: "+countContact);

            return vi;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }   
    }
```

When I running app, It's load all contact but when I click button Home and change some information in Address book then click icon app to open app again. And onResume() method not working.

Here my onResume()

```
@Override
        protected void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();

            if (lv != null)
            {
                updateData();
            }
        }

        private void updateData()
        {
            getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
            ma = new MyAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(ma);
            ma.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

So some body help me! Plz!

Comment: try it as `ma.clear();getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());lv.setAdapter(ma);ma.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK what is clear(); I dont have that method in MyAdapter

Comment: add `public void clear() { name1.clear();phno1.clear(); email1.clear();}` in MyAdapter then try

Answer (score 0):

Try by Replacing your updateData():

```
        private void updateData()
        {
            getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
            ma.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: You just try to update your listview data by simply onclick of button & check that whether you are getting updated data in listview?

Answer (score 0):

You may be referencing an old ListView (lv) that is not the new ListView you see when you resume your Activity. Try getting the reference to lv again using Activity.findViewById(R.id.xxxx) in onResume().

You could also try reusing the old adapter instead of creating a brand new one (by clearing it and updating it's content). If you're reusing the old adapter, just make sure you give the old adapter to the new ListView using ListView.setAdapter(ma).

You should also have MyAdapter.getItemId(int position) return position instead of 0.